# Print the Result of a mysqli SELECT Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

hello im doing an app where it manages house owners and tenants connection, im trying to print an apartment id for specific apartment but keeps getting error

this my code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$query="select ID from apartment WHERE owner= '$user'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
print_r($res)
```

im getting this error

> "mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )"

Comment: Where is `$conn` set? Where do you `session_start`? How is `javascript` involved?

Comment: From the [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) manual page: "_Returns false on failure. For successful queries which produce a result set, such as SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN, mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries, mysqli_query() will return true._" You'd need to fetch the results first

Comment: You get an empty result, which is not an error at all... there is just no record matching the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to print the query itself, not the result.

Add something like:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$query="select ID from apartment WHERE owner= '$user'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); // this line 
print_r($res)
```